# Distribution of the components of a multivariate random variable given its characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose we are given a $n$-dimensional random variable $Z$ with normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\Sigma)$. I know that the characteristic fumction of $Z$ is given by $\Phi_Z(t)=e^{t^T(i \mu - \frac{1}{2} \Sigma t)}$. Can we read off the distributions of the component vectors of $Z$ from $\Phi_Z$? What about the case when $Z$ is not normally distributed?

Comment: Yes, take $t^T:=(\lambda,0,\ldots,0)$ to get the characteristic function of the first component, $t^T:=(0,\lambda,0,\ldots,0)$ to get that of the second component, etc.

Comment: What do you mean "read off"? Even in the 1d, non-normal case, you generally have to perform an inverse fourier transform in order to recover the distribution from the characteristic function.